# how does this typedef syntax works..?

Tags: c++, typedef, ostream

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef ostream& (*T)(ostream& , int);
class Base
{
    T fun;
    int  var;
    public:
    Base(T func, int arg): fun(func) , var(arg)
    {};
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Base& obj)
    {
        return obj.fun(o,obj.var);
    }
};

ostream& odisp(ostream& o, int i);
{
    o<<”i=”<<i<<endl;
    return o;
}
Base disp(int i)
{
    return base(odisp, i)
};
```

I am totally stuck since the first line since i cant figure out how this typedef works.. it looks like a pointer to function syntax but again ostream has me puzzled..?? pls do explain how this whole code works..??

Comment: `iostream.h` is long gone. Use `iostream` instead and prefix  everything in it with `std::`. While I'm at it, `conio.h` is very old and deprecated as well. Neither of those are even mentioned in the spec. Anyway, `std::ostream` is the type of `std::cout`. Replace it with any other type if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

As it has been pointed out, `iostream.h` and `conio.h` are not standard headers for C++ programs. The correct header include statement for the IO streams library is `#include <iostream>`, without the extension.

```
typedef ostream& (*T)(ostream& , int);
```

This creates a `typedef` named `T` which is a pointer to a function with these properties:

- returns a reference to `ostream`
- accepts two parameters, in this order:

  - a reference to an `ostream`
  - `int` value

`ostream`, assuming it's referring to `std::ostream`, is itself a `typedef` of [`std::basic_ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), which is found in the C++ standard library. It is defined as:

```
namespace std {
    typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream;
}
```

Objects `std::cout` are instances of `std::ostream`.

```
class Base
{
    T fun; // (1)
    int var; // (2)
public:
    Base(T func, int arg): fun(func) , var(arg) {}; // (3)

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Base& obj) // (4)
    {
        return obj.fun(o, obj.var);
    }
};
```

This is a class that holds two things: (1) a pointer to a function as described above and (2) an integer. The constructor (3) allows users of the class to instantiate it with a function pointer and an integer.

The friend function declaration (4) overloads the left bitshift operator `<<`. This sort of overloading is called [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). By convention, The operator `<<` is also called the stream insertion operator in the context of IO streams.

Note that friend functions defined this way are actually not members of `Base`, and thus do not receive a `this` pointer (hence, the need for a separate `Base&` parameter).

```
ostream& odisp(ostream& o, int i);
{
    o << "i=" << i << endl;
    return o;
}
```

This is a function called `odisp`. It takes in a reference to an `ostream` and an integer. If you pass in the integer 42, it prints out the passed-in integer in this form:

> i=42

```
Base disp(int i)
{
    return base(odisp, i)
};
```

This function has multiple syntax errors and will not run as-is:

- `base` is probably meant to be `Base`. In this case it would construct a `Base` temporary and returns it.
- Missing a semicolon.

These issues are somewhat fundamental to the language. You may want to pick up a [good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which will cover these issues.

Comment: As a note to avoid confusion, `operator<<` is the left bit shift operator, but it is also commonly known as the *stream insertion operator* when used for this purpose. Since it was very early on that this happened, it's become a sort of standard name for the operator, but it still really is the left bit shift operator in disguise.

Comment: nice answer except for a little error at the end: `return Base(odisp,i);` would be the correct call to the constructor of `Base` with `odisp` the function (taken via function pointer). (I don't understand, though, why `Base` is called "Base".)